# Forcing write(2) to return 0

Tags: file-descriptors, testing, write

I am writing unit tests and would like to test some code's handling of the case where a call to write(2) returns zero. As ever, it would be nice to keep the test as authentic as possible.

I can use a file-descriptor of any kind for this purpose, as long as it returns zero on a call to write(2). I can also pass in pretty much any data of any size to write.

However, I would like to be able to change the descriptor's behaviour from another thread, after zero has been returned a few times, so just writing data of length zero is not acceptable.

Can anyone think of a reasonably portable, reliable means of getting a filedescriptor into such a state? The target is recent Linux, but working more broadly (*BSD, OS X, etc), would be great, if possible.

Comment: Any reason why you don't wrap `write()` in a thin wrapper that depends on some global state that you change and test against that wrapper (with appropriate state), thus simulating a 0 return from write()?

Comment: This is what I'm doing at the moment but it uglifies the code. I should probably look at an AOP type way of avoiding that. Maybe I'll stick to doing it like this: there are probably other tests where I want to fake write in other ways. If you want to make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If influencing the actual input is difficult (such as reacting on a disc error), you should make a thin wrapper around the function, that depends on some global state. In this case I would put such a wrapper around `write()` to return 0 or the actual return from `write()`.

If the overhead of the wrapper is too big use some `#define` to be able to leave out the wrapper code in the production system altogether, but at least you can test the layers on top of `write()` to react correct during unittests by setting the global state as necessary.